# Opening ASP.Net pages in Java application

Tags: java, asp.net

Currently we have a Java application and .Net application running in two servers. 
We have a requirement to call a set of pages developed in Asp.Net into a Java application.

Follows the brief explanation:
1.  Suppose there is a running java application.
2.  On click of a link (Say "Edit Profile") from Java app, a set of pages supposed to start from ASP.Net.
3.  On this call, some data need to be passed from Java app to Asp.Net app to authenticate and start the *Task (set of pages doing a particular task).

Your inputs for the below will be much appreciated.
1. How do we pass the data from Java to .Net in a secured manner (Other than Query String) and open the .aspx page after authentication. Means how do we know that the calling site (in this case Java app) is authorized to access the set of pages from Asp.Net app?
2. How to return the *Task result to Java app back from .Net.

Answer (score 0):

If the ASP.NET app offers a .NET API to pass that information (so that that functionality can be accessed from .NET code), you can call it from your Java app using JNBridgePro (a Java/.NET bridge).  For more information, see www.jnbridge.com, or contact us.  (Disclosure: I work for JNBridge.)